# How can I add a line break for the text of a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibutton

I want to know how to have a multi-line label on a UIButton.

Answer (score 5):

Use the UIButton's titleLabel, specifically titleLabel.numberOfLines property:

```
titleLabel
A view that displays the value of the currentTitle property for a button. (read-only)

@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UILabel *titleLabel
Discussion
Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these 
properties to configure the appearance of the button label. For example:

UIButton *button                  = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
button.titleLabel.shadowOffset    = CGSizeMake (1.0, 0.0);
The titleLabel property returns a value even if the button has not been displayed yet.
The value of the property is nil for system buttons.
```